# Fingerprint scanner for Dell XPS 15 (7590) running Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dell, fingerprint-reader

No matter what I try to install, the fingerprint option never appears as an option in the "User" configuration. This works fine in Windows 11 as I have dual boot, but not in Ubuntu

Comment: Please add more info. What did you try to install? Have you followed any guides?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. What is the chipset of the scanner? Then google the name of the chipset and support Ubuntu. To see if your model is supported. Also mention the version of Ubuntu you are using, the kernel etc. See also 'how to ask a question?' on this site.

Comment: I confirm, this XPS 7590 can use the fingerprint in Windows XX but not in Ubuntu.
I used Xubuntu 20.04, now 22.04, fingerprint never appears.
It is a Goodix device, an lsusb command code in the console returns :
**Bus 001 Device 005: ID 27c6:5395 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader**
It seems some peoples are working on this specific device but it is had to reverse-engeenering, and Goodix don't have drivers for this.

Comment: Is your fingerprint device a Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader?